# Hibernate Exception-Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx-8, rmi, netbeans-8

I hava a problem in the server side of my project. I used hibernate for this. There are three entities such as account,chat and chataccount. Account entity is shown below. I didn't use any annotation to getters or setters.

```
@Entity
public class Account {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int aid;

 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Customer customer;

 private String email;
 private String password;
 private int real_payment;

 public Account() {
 }
```

and my chat entity.

```
@Entity
public class Chat {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int chatId;

 private String description;
 private String time;

 public Chat() {
 }
```

and finally chat account is here.This is associate entity.

```
@Entity
public class ChatAccount {

 @EmbeddedId
 private ChatPK chatPK;

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Chat chat;

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Account account;

 private int receiveAid;

 public ChatAccount() {
 }
```

The error is shown below.Please help me to solve this.

server side:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.coinnet.entity.Account, at table: ChatAccount, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(account)]
```

client side:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.MappingException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:247)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.checkLogin(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you tried clean compile?

Comment: yes i did it number of times. but the result is same..Have you an any idea??

Comment: guys anyone can help me please!!!